# What phonetic alphabet is used here?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

Can someone tell me what phonetic alphabet is used here? Also, how is this word pronounced?

[image: jĭ′gà]

Update: This is a scientific term from a 1976 National Bureau of Standards manual. The original word is written *giga*. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is that it is probably one of the phonemic systems that are now found only in American dictionaries, e.g. AHD and MW. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English for a comparison chart.

Comment: @choster Surely the whole point of a phonetic language is to negate the need for both of those things? :) I've updated the question just the same.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt No, it doesn't negate them. There are countless groups of words that can be pronounced identically, and whose meaning cannot be inferred from their pronunciation; consider *to*, *two*, and *too*.

Comment: @choster I'm not asking for a definition, nor am I remotely interested in one (I already have it), I'm asking solely for the pronunciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering its date and source, the symbols appear to be a phonetic representation of the kind that has been abandoned in most of the world, but remains entrenched in the major American dictionaries and in American primary and secondary education. See for example the [American Heritage Dictionary pronunciation key](https://www.ahdictionary.com/application/resources/misc/pronkey.pdf), [Merriam-Webster Guide to Pronunciation](http://assets2.merriam-webster.com/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf), 
or the [Wikipedia United States dictionary transcription key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:United_States_dictionary_transcription).

The breve (˘) is not used by Random House, Merriam-Webster, or the New Oxford American Dictionary, but it is commonly used to mark a "short" vowel sound, and is used in the AHD system. The prime mark indicating stress but positioned at the end of the stressed syllable is also a mark of the AHD. Using the AHD key then, the [SI prefix](http://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/prefixes.html) for *giga-*, meaning 10<sup>9</sup>, and represented as

> jĭ′gä

would in IPA be something like

> 'dʒɪgɑ or 'dʒɪgə

akin to *jig*.

This pronunciation seems strange nowadays, because we have become accustomed to the 'hard g' \gɪgɑ-\ pronunciation in words like *gigabyte* and *gigahertz*. This prefix as a multiplier was uncommon outside of science and industry until fairly recently, however, and some used to prefer the 'soft g' \dʒ\ variant— endorsed by the IEEE, ANSI, and indeed the [NBS](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/TN/nbstechnicalnote938.pdf), whose successor, the National Institute of Standards and Technology, [sticks by this pronunciation](https://www2.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/prefixes) to the present day. MW also [retains the 'soft g'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giga-?pronunciation&lang=en_us&dir=g&file=giga0001) in its recorded pronunciation, and notes both pronunciations, but most other dictionaries seem to have dropped it in favor of the 'hard g' (\g) variety.

Famously, Doc Brown's time machine in the *Back to the Future* films is said to use *[1.21 gigawatts](http://www.wired.com/2013/09/how-do-you-get-1-21-gigawatts-for-your-time-machine/)* of power, pronounced with the 'soft g'. This was retconned by later fans to *[jigowatts](http://wheels.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/04/08/you-say-gigawatt-i-say-jigowatt/)* — ironic, because his pronunciation of *gigawatt* would have been unexceptional in the 1950s U.S.