# Pronunciation of the letter "c" or "ce" in Australian English

Tags: pronunciation, australian-english, medical

In an Australian TV program the disease "encephalitis" was pronounced "enKephalitis."  Is there a rule about the pronunciation of the letter "c" in Australian English?

Comment: Apparently both hard and soft *c* pronunciations exist in [British and American English](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/encephalitis).  Perhaps it was somebody of Greek descent (originally from κεφαλή meaning *head*) or who had a classical education

Comment: This (using a hard 'c') is actually truer to the Greek roots of the word and is thus arguably more "correct".  From Wikipedia:  *"The word is from Ancient Greek ἐγκέφαλος, enképhalos "brain"* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encephalitis However, due to it being written with a "c", the soft-c pronounciation has grown more common.  I don't think that this trend is particularly Australian.

Comment: I'd agree with @Henry that people who have studied ancient Greek (which, along with Latin, makes learning anatomy much easier), are more likely to use the "k" sound.

Comment: We use 'c' mostly because the Romans used 'c' rather than 'k' when they borrowed Greek words - the Latin alphabet had a 'k', but it was very restricted in use, and not usually used to represent Greek kappa.

Comment: You can find alternate spellings throughout the dictionary.  Here is one: **Celt |kelt selt|**

Answer (score 4):

The pronunciation of *encephalitis* with /k/ is not specific to Australian English. The competing pronunciation with /s/ is also not exclusive to any one particular country (or as far as I can tell, era). Ebenezer Cobham Brewer, a 19th-century lexicographer born in England, recorded and prescribed /s/ in *encephalitis* and related words ("[Errors of Speech and of Spelling](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DUFAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA296)", Volume 1, 1877; page 296).

The variation between /k/ and /s/ in this word does not really follow any regular pattern at all. Some people apparently felt at some point that /k/ was more appropriate in this word, since it's closer to the consonant sound used in the Ancient Greek word from which it is derived.

I think this it's silly to feel this way: many words spelled with "c" used to have /k/ if you go far enough back (such as "child" and "center"). Also, it's not like we pronounce the rest of the word according to Ancient Greek pronunciation. But ultimately, that's just a matter of opinion: there's no way to definitively state that one pronunciation is "correct" or "incorrect". You can see some discussion here: [Pronunciation of "encephalitis"](https://groups.google.com/g/alt.usage.english/c/p9P8kdiF_EU)

Anyway, even though there is no consistent pattern or rule, there are a few other irregular oddities like this. Some people pronounce "proboscis" with /k/, and everyone nowadays pronounces /k/ in "sceptic" (although many people also change the spelling to "k"). *Cephalopod,* from the same root as *encephalitis,* seems to only be recorded in dictionaries with /s/—which is what I've always heard it with—but a search of [Internet discussions](http://66.39.159.169/talk/viewtopic.php?t=24712&start=0&sid=a9a03650ddbeec56442277e8e7533fb9) [reveals](https://www.susanelainejones.com/post/2018/02/07/frog-pants) that a /k/ pronunciation of *cephalopod* exists.

The same inconsistency applies to some words spelled with "g." As mentioned at that link, in most words from Greek, g is "soft" /dʒ/ before *e, i* or *y.* But in a handful of cases, such as *[gyn(a)ecology](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/09/gynaecology.html)/-ist* and the prefix *[giga-](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344811/what-phonetic-alphabet-is-used-here/344874#344874),* it's now common to use /g/. (This spelling pattern is probably less surprising than the use of /k/ in "ce", since English also has a sizable number of words from other sources with "hard g" before *e,* *i* or *y*.)

Comment: The alternative to a hard C would be to say 'septic', which doesn't really do the business.

Comment: @WS2: **septicism** *- the belief that there is no such thing as [septicaemia*](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Blood-poisoning/Pages/Introduction.aspx)

Comment: @WS2: It's true the words would be homophones in that case. Nonetheless, the French seem to get by using the same pronunciation for *sceptique* and *septique.*

Answer (score 2):

English phonetician J. C. Wells has this remark in his pronunciation dictionary:

> - In words containing *(-)cephal-*, the medical profession in Britain generally prefers **k**.  The alternative pronunciation with **s** is nevertheless widespread and preferred in American English.

The entry for encephalitis is the following:

> - BrE enˌkefəˈlaitɪs, (less common) enˌsefəˈlaitɪs
> - AmE enˌsefəˈlait̬əs

Answer (score -2):

It has nothing to do with an Australian-English rule for the letter ‘c’. The word ‘encephalitis’ comes from Greek, and the ‘c’ has always been a ‘k’ in this instance.

The confusion came about when Americans began to mispronounce the beginning of the word as ‘en-seff…’ rather than ‘en-keff…’and this mispronunciation has sadly (like too many Americanisms) spread via TV and cinema.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).